# PHP accepting json from $http.post vs $.post

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have an angular app where I setup the following json object:

```
var newUser = {
    username: $scope.form.username,
    password: $scope.form.password,
    userTypeId: 1,
    email: $scope.form.email
};
```

I then attempted to post to my php backend:

```
$http.post(
    ENVIRONMENT.backendUrl + '/users/add/.json?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM',
    newUser
).success(function() {
    alert("success");
}).error(function() {
    alert("failure");
});
```

Oddly enough, none of the variables were there in the `$_POST` array, nor in the `php://input`. But when I changed the post to use jquery instead, it work:

```
$.post(
    ENVIRONMENT.backendUrl + '/users/add/.json?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM',
    newUser
).success(function() {
    alert( "success");
}).error(function() {
    alert( "failure");
});
```

Any idea on why these two ways of posting cause a difference in the $_POST value?

Comment: that's not json. that's just a plain JS data structure. json is a text-encoding of a data structure.

Comment: use `newUser = JSON.stringify(newUser)` to convert JS object to JSON

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with PHP. Do you see network activity following the `$http.post()` operation?

Comment: what @ksealey said is correct first convert it to JSON and then decode it as JSON .